# Does puppeteer support creating pdf/a?

Tags: pdf-generation, puppeteer

Does puppeteer support the creation of pdf/a? Or just standard pdfs?

If not than does anyone know an answer to this question?
[How to create pdf/a-1b file using node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570586/how-to-create-pdf-a-1b-file-using-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, with time passing on and having some experience with puppeteer, it does not support creation of pdf/a. We are now targeting a proprietary solution.

Comment: Would you mind sharing if (and which) you found another solution for creating PDF/A documents?