# Does Puppeteer support PDF/A-3?

Tags: .net, puppeteer

I want to convert HTML to PDF/A-3 using Puppeteer.
I read Puppeteer's documentation and they don't seem to support that.
There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186252/does-puppeteer-support-creating-pdf-a) from 3 years ago and the answer was that Puppeteer does not support PDF/A.
I wanted to provide the interested parties (including me) with a recent update.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "and that needs human involvement"
I need a programmatic way to create PDF/A-3 with an embedded file using .NET

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's related to Government requirements, however not European ones. I saw there are some libraries that claim to support PDF/A generation and I plan to look at them. I hope all these complexities in regard to the requirements for this format are solved by the library (especially having in mind it most probably will be with a commercial license).